# Using embedded ruby in application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm following the Heroku image upload [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) which includes the following code in application.js -

```
fileInput.fileupload({
      fileInput:       fileInput,
      url:             '<%= @s3_direct_post.url %>',
      type:            'POST',
      autoUpload:       true,
      formData:         <%= @s3_direct_post.fields.to_json.html_safe %>,
      paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e. name="user[avatar_url]"
      dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
      replaceFileInput: false
    });
```

...you can see that `formData:` does not have quotes around the erb - this is causing a javascript error when I deploy the code - `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

That erb should be in quotes, right? Any comment greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes. But worse than that, `application.js` is a static file (or rather 'quasi-static' because of the asset pipeline) and it won't be processed by erb. So even if you don't have JS syntax errors, it isn't gonna work.

Comment: You need to add this code in some .js.erb file

Comment: I've solved the immediate problem by pasting the code into `/assets/javascripts/somejavascriptfile.js.erb`- it's left me with other bugs, but this first one is solved, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that - it might work in development, but will break in production as default production configuration assumes all the assets are precompiled and are served by the server. This obviously can be changed, but might cause some performance issues.

If you need to pass any data from your controller to your javascript, use `gon` gem:

controller:

```
gon.fileUpload = {
  url: @s3_direct_post.url,
  data: @s3_direct_post.fields.to_json
}
```

Then you can use it within 100% static javascript:

```
fileInput.fileupload({
      fileInput:       fileInput,
      url:             gon.fileUpload.url
      type:            'POST',
      autoUpload:       true,
      formData:         gon.fileUpload.data,
      paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e. name="user[avatar_url]"
      dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
      replaceFileInput: false
    });
```

Naturally you need to follow gon installation guide.

Comment: I think it's not gonna work even in development - because `application.js` isn't an `erb` file, so it won't be preprocessed by `erb` before rendering.

Comment: Well, what I meant was that even if he makes it work in dev. :)

Comment: I've solved my immediate problem by moving the code into a .js.erb file, but thanks for this suggestion - I'll have a look at the gon gem :)